# What causes an indexer to get marked as "Scheduled" in EE

Tags: indexing, solr

Something causes my Solr search index to drop and slowly reindex over and over throughout the day making products disappear.

If the Magento indexer is running on every cron run, how does it decide to mark an indexer as "scheduled" even though my Index Management settings are set to "Update on Save" for search.

Seems to be based on the changelog. Is there a magic number of changelog entries in `catalogsearch_fulltext_cl` that triggers the scheduling? It's not any sort of event that i can tell. Nothing i edit and save triggers the schedule; it just seems to happen randomly.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the issue. I was running a price reindex from the cron every 3 hours and i found this event in the Enterprise/Search code:

`app/code/core/Enterprise/Search/etc/config.xml:`

```
<after_reindex_process_catalog_product_price>
    <observers>
        <enterprise_search>
            <class>enterprise_search/observer</class>
            <method>runFulltextReindexAfterPriceReindex</method>
        </enterprise_search>
    </observers>
</after_reindex_process_catalog_product_price>
```

Which will reindex search after a price reindex.

Answer (score 0):

Going through the setup for Magento 2 it has you set the cron to run every minute. once every three hours might not be frequent enough.

I think the cron jobs get run constantly but only when they hit designated events or time slots do they actually reindex the various indexes.